# Make - Internal compiler Error under QT 5.14.2 "Q_CORE_EXPORT"

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, makefile, mingw

I just installed QT Creator with QT under Win10 to build an already existing project. (Under Ubuntu everything went fine running the Make file). I'm not an expert for QT therefore I'm not able to find out how to resolve the error:

> C:\Qt\5.14.2\mingw73_64\include/QtCore/qfloat16.h:102:54: internal compiler error: in make_rtl_for_nonlocal_decl, at cp/decl.c:6590
>        Q_CORE_EXPORT static const quint32 mantissatable[];

My gcc version is 8.3.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project). Is there something missing or broken in the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out from qmake.stash, that the included script for creating the make file always referenced a false path for the gcc compiler. I therefore build i manually with the QT Creator and it worked as expected. So I guess the fault was due to different paths for gcc in the environmental variables.

Comment: Note that Qt Creator doesn't do any "magic". From compile output you can check the commands it runs when building your project, and if you launch the "Qt command prompt" (which should be available from the Windows start menu), and run the same commands manually, you should get the same result as from Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2):

On windows, you generally need to have a Qt which was built with the same (or compatible, but that can be hard to verify) compiler and relevant build options, as what you are using to build your application.

I doubt you will find a pre-built Qt SDK for that version of *gcc*, so if you want to use it, you should build Qt from sources. It can be a bit tedious on Windows, there are a fewf prerequisites you have to get etc. I recommend you use the Qt online installer to install a MinGW version of Qt SDK, and matching version of MinGW (also offered by the Qt installer.

Comment: It's somehow not possible for me to resolve this error. I just installed the QT Version which was used implementing this project but I'm running into the same problem...

Comment: Are you sure it was built with the same compiler?

Comment: I just found out from qmake.stash, that the included script for creating the make file always referenced a false path for the gcc compiler. I therefore build i manually with the QT Creator and it worked as expected.  So I guess the fault was due to different paths for gcc in  the environmental variables

Comment: You could write that as an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the bug, there is a link to the patch: https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5006

Also you can just downgrade to mingw gcc 8.2.0